# Web API Controller defining Routes

Tags: c#, controller, webapi

I'm not sure about how Route attribute works for my web API controller. I was recently asked to implement some requests with specific routes (for example: POST with route "/collection/item"). Is that any difference between this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/collection/item")]  
    public async Task<ActionResult<DataItem>> PostItem(DataItem item)
    {
      ...
    }

}
```

and this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/api/collection/item")]  
    public async Task<ActionResult<DataItem>> PostItem(DataItem item)
    {
       ...
    } 

}
```

Is it possible that some of these options is wrong?

Comment: remove ~/ and it would work
so will be [Route("api/collection/item")] or [Route("collection/item")]

Comment: But I would like to know if I there is any difference if I use again "/api" in every request or not

Comment: your request will be like https://localhost:5000/api/collection/item

Comment: how can you use again "/api" i didn't get what you mean

Comment: yeah i got what you mean, 
yeah there's a different sure

Comment: I mean , would it be the same path if I use ~/collection/item and ~/api/collection/item having already defined route on top  - api/[controller] ?

Comment: And in this situation, if I'm asked to set route for API request to /collection/item, should I write "~/api/collection/item", "~/collection/item" or simply "/collection/item" ?

Comment: just "collection/item" without "~/"

Comment: I'm asking because I was doing some test recently and I wrote "~/api/collection/item" and got nothing but 0 points for this exercise

Comment: Okay, so If I'm asked to set specific route for request, it's better not to add anything before this route

Comment: read this article to understand
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1